# An elegant way of handling dynamic honorifics within a Node.js website?

Tags: html, sql, node.js, express

### The Problem

I've built a **Node.js** website using the **Express** framework. It's essentially a front end for an **SQL database**, which holds the details of various famous individuals, living and dead, often in the form of short strings and numerical data, but sometimes also in the form of **fragments of prose**.

People's **honorifics**, pronouns, styles, etc are not fixed, and this is causing my database to be **higher maintenance** than I would like. Women are the most troublesome in this regard - there's a statement that could be taken out of context! - Miss Atkins marries and becomes Mrs Miggins, and then I have to change every mention of 'Miss Atkins' to 'Mrs Miggins', manually! But there are a number of similar circumstances: someone changes his or her name, someone acquires a doctorate, someone acquires a royal or noble title, etc.

### A Solution?

I already have a step in my code such that, before a response is returned, a few **find-and-replace** functions go through that response's HTML. I use this to highlight a particular set of strings in red wherever they appear on my website. I was thinking that I could use a similar method to tackle the honorifics issue.

More specifically, I was thinking of implementing the following:

1. A kind of **custom HTML entity**, `&honorfic;`, which would be used in the prose fields of the database like so: 'Although she was born in France, Miss Atkins grew up in the UK.' --> 'Although she was born in France, &honorific; grew up in the UK.'
2. An 'honorific' field in the database, such that there was a record for each individual.
3. A function, similar to those described above, which, when responding to a request for an individual's profile page, would replace `&honorifc;` with the desired string.

**Is this a sensible way of tackling the above problem? Is there a better way?**

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an HTML template system where you dynamically supply things like names or titles or honorifics rather than baking them into the HTML and the HTML template engine takes care of filling in the appropriate pieces of the template based on a set of data you pass the template renderer.  You don't have to invent such a thin yourself.  There are [dozens](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) of HTML template systems for Express.  EJS, Pug, Handlebars, Nunjucks are some of the better known.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but, with respect, I think you may have misunderstood my question somewhat. (It's probably that I phrased my question less clearly than I might have.) I'm very comfortable with HTML template systems; when I started using Pug, it was still called Jade! What I'm trying to achieve is to store data that is liable to need updating - such as a paragraph of text in which, at several points, a young woman is referred to using her surname - **in an SQL database**, and then deliver that data in a readable form to someone visiting the website.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking then.  It appears you already know the solution is to parameterize the things that might change so you can dynamically insert them at some later time.  `&honorific;` is such an example.  So, what are you looking for from us?  There is no other such solution.  Insert an easy to find placeholder and then substitute in the current value for that placeholder whenever you need the current rendered version.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well, sir, as it says in the the last line of my question, I want to know, Is this a sensible way of tackling the above problem? Is there a better way? And **I think you've just answered both of those concerns**. If you were to paste your comment into a more formal answer, then I would happily accept it. If you'd prefer to leave things as they are, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you already fully understand a solution where you parameterize the things that might change so you can dynamically insert them at some later time.
`&honorific;` is such an example.  Any content which might dynamically change later (and which you need to be able to adjust when it does change) should probably be parameterized like this.

There is no other magic solution for free form data. Insert an easy to find placeholder and then substitute in the current value for that placeholder whenever you need the current rendered version.

This is conceptually similar to what HTML template engines do, which you already seem to be familiar with.  In fact, you could even just use their parsing and parameter systems if you didn't feel the need to invent your own.

> Is this a sensible way of tackling the above problem?

Yes.

> Is there a better way?

Not really.  For very structured content, you might dynamically build the content from pieces rather than starting with a fully worded template and substituting in just certain things that were parameterized.  For example, if you wanted to print someone's address, you probably would just generate the address directly from data in the database via code without using a template.  But, if you have lots of free-form prose intermixed with a few parameterized pieces of data, the parameters embedded in the free form text that are fill-in upon demand is a simple way to solve the problem.